# IUPAC Nomenclature using Iso alkoxy groups

Tags: nomenclature

Is the name of the compound    4-isopropoxy-pentan-2-one or is it 4-(1-methylethoxy)pentan-2-one... Are both the correct "systematic" names or am I messing up:'.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the prefix names ‘1-methylethyl’ or ‘isopropyl’ may be used in general nomenclature; the preferred prefix, however, is **propan-2-yl.**

The relevant rule for the systematic names of ethers in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)* reads as follows.

> **63.2.2.1** Systematic names
>
> **P-63.2.2.1.1** Substituent prefix names for $\ce{R'-O-{}}$ groups are formed by concatenation, i.e., by adding the prefix ‘oxy’ to the substituent prefix name for the group $\ce{R'}$. These compound prefixes require the numerical multiplying prefixes ‘bis’, ‘tris’, etc.

However, a problem with this rule is that many examples in the Blue Book were wrong and had to be corrected because they ignored the rules for parentheses. Note that parentheses are used around compound prefixes according to Rule P-16.5.1.1 and around simple substituent prefixes to separate locants of the same type referring to different structural elements according to Rule P-16.5.1.2.

Therefore, the systematic name for the compound that is given in the question is
**4-[(propan-2-yl)oxy]pentan-2-one**
since the simple substituent prefix ‘propan-2-yl’ includes a locant that does not refer to the same structural element as the initial locant ‘4-’ and ‘(propan-2-yl)oxy’ is a compound prefix.

[image: 4-[(propan-2-yl)oxy]pentan-2-one]